# TensorBoard error - [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to run TensorBoard with the following code

```
%load_ ext tensorboard.notebook

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant( [100,200,300], name = 'x')
y = tf.constant([1,2,3], name = 'y')

sum_x = tf.reduce_sum(x, name="sum_x"
prod y = tf.reduce_prod(y,name="prod_y")

final div = tf.div(sum_x, prod_y, name = 'final div’)
final_mean = tf.reduce_mean([sum_x, prod_y], name = 'final_mean*)
sess=tf .Session()

print ("x: ",sess.run(x))
print ("y: ", sess.run(y))
print ("sum(x): ", sess.run(sum_x))
print ("prod(y): ", sess.run(prod_y))
print ("sum(x)/prod(y): ", sess.run(final_ div))
print ("mean(sum(x), prod(y)): ", sess.run(final_mean))

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('janani_ex_2', sess.graph)
writer.close()

sess.close()

%tensorboard --logdir = 'janani_ex_2'
```

This displays `Launching tensorboard` and then run into a `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19BrR.png).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the code and error here ?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you need to change this line

`%tensorboard --logdir = 'janani_ex_2'`

to

`%tensorboard --logdir '.\janani_ex_2'`

I'm assuming that the folder `janani_ex_2` includes your logs and it's located inside the folder, where your jupyter notebook is in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *not* using Jupyter notebook, then in the folder with the tensorboard objects, use this:

```
tensorboard --logdir ./
```

It will look in the current folder to get the files.  To get to the folder, type cd and then copy and paste the name of the folder.